# Refactoring if statement in java

Tags: java, if-statement, refactoring

I need some help refactoring this if-statement. I thought of declaring the percentage as constants. I also thought to make a method that includes the code inside the if brackets. What else can i do?

```
if(totalReceiptsAmount >= getIncome() && totalReceiptsAmount <  0.20 * getIncome())
        setTaxIncrease(getBasicTax() + 0.05 * getBasicTax());
    if(totalReceiptsAmount >=  0.20 * getIncome() && totalReceiptsAmount <  0.40 * getIncome())
        setTaxIncrease(getBasicTax() - 0.05 * getBasicTax());
    if(totalReceiptsAmount >=  0.40 * getIncome() && totalReceiptsAmount <  0.60 * getIncome())
        setTaxIncrease(getBasicTax() - 0.10 * getBasicTax());
    if(totalReceiptsAmount >=  0.60 * getIncome())
        setTaxIncrease(getBasicTax() - 0.15 * getBasicTax());
```

Comment: Use `else if`s to remove the double checks and factor out the function call, storing only the percentages inside the ifs.

Comment: well i did that at first, but our professor told us to refactor `else if` with only `if`

Comment: That feels wrong... Any reason for that?

Comment: This question is more appropriate for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: The first `if` - how is `totalReceiptsAmount` going to be both greater than `getIncome()` and less than  `0.2 * getIncome()`? I'm assuming the income is not negative.

Comment: Have you considered storing the result of `GetIncome()` in a variable? No need to keep calling it from what I can tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem in your code is probably the **duplication of code**, meaning if you want to change e.g., the condition, you'd probably have to apply the same change in all four conditions. So you could try to factor out the common functionality, as you already suggested for the conditionals. So you could define a method

```
private boolean receiptsAmountIsBetweenFactorOfXAndYOfIncome(double x, double y){
    return totalReceiptsAmount >= x * getIncome() && totalReceiptsAmount < y  * getIncome();
}
```

and update your if-statements accordingly:

```
if(receiptsAmountIsBetweenFactorOfXAndYOfIncome(0, 0.2))
    setTaxIncrease(getBasicTax() + 0.05 * getBasicTax());
if(receiptsAmountIsBetweenFactorOfXAndYOfIncome(0.2, 0.4))
    setTaxIncrease(getBasicTax() - 0.05 * getBasicTax());
if(receiptsAmountIsBetweenFactorOfXAndYOfIncome(0.4, 0.6))
    setTaxIncrease(getBasicTax() - 0.10 * getBasicTax());
if(receiptsAmountIsBetweenFactorOfXAndYOfIncome(0.6, 1))
    setTaxIncrease(getBasicTax() - 0.15 * getBasicTax());
```

---

Now, there's still duplication in the body of the if statements. So you could introduce an other method:

```
private void increaseTaxByFactorOfX(double x){
    setTaxIncrease(getBasicTax() + x * getBasicTax());
}
```

and update the if-statements again:

```
if(receiptsAmountIsBetweenFactorOfXAndYOfIncome(0, 0.2))
    increaseTaxByFactorOfX(0.05);
if(receiptsAmountIsBetweenFactorOfXAndYOfIncome(0.2, 0.4))
    increaseTaxByFactorOfX(-0.05);
if(receiptsAmountIsBetweenFactorOfXAndYOfIncome(0.4, 0.6))
    increaseTaxByFactorOfX(-0.10);
if(receiptsAmountIsBetweenFactorOfXAndYOfIncome(0.6, 1))
    increaseTaxByFactorOfX(-0.15);
```

---

Now, if you want, you can detect a pattern in the used numericals, or simply hardcode the numericals in an array or a list and use a loop instead of multiple similar if-statements:

```
double[] factorOfIncome = {0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 1};
double[] taxIncreaseFactor = {0.05, -0.05, -0.10, -0.15};

for(int i = 0; i<taxIncreaseFactor.length; i++)
    if(receiptsAmountIsBetweenFactorOfXAndYOfIncome(factorOfIncome[i], factorOfIncome[i+1]))
        increaseTaxByFactorOfX(taxIncreaseFactor[i]);
```

This last refactoring step gets completely rid of the duplication, but in my opinion makes the code a bit less understandable.

**Edit:** Note that I assumed that the first conditional should be

```
if(totalReceiptsAmount >= 0 * getIncome() && //...
```

as it really looks like this is what you intended to write. If this isn't the case, then the first conditional would need to be treated separately.